Memory issue about pointer that points to std::vector
I was doing an algorithm problem about SPFA, and I used std::vector to store the weighted edge of the graph, where I have a pointer array that points to it:
struct e{
    int to,p,v;
    e(int _to_,int _p_, int _v_) {to = _to_, p = _p_, v = _v_;}
};
vector <e> edge[maxN];
e* ptr_arr[maxM]; //ptr array points to the struct object

for(int i=0; i<m;i++){scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&v_temp);  
    edge[a].push_back(e(b,0,v_temp));
    ptr_arr[i]=&edge[a].back();}
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){scanf("%d",&p_temp);
    ptr_arr[i]->p=p_temp;
    cout << ptr_arr[i]->v;}

The problem input is like this,
5 6
2 3 2 
5 2 5 
1 5 7 
3 4 3 
1 3 5 
4 1 8 
2 3 1 4 1 3

I need to modify p for every edge that is stored in edge[maxN], so I keep track of the address of each element in ptr_arr. When I was debugging, I discover that for this case, ptr_arr[2] and ptr_arr[5] points to the same address, which should not be. I am wondering what causes this problem?
I am guessing there's something to do with the memory allocating for vector array but I am not so sure, and I cannot grasp the core cause for this problem.

Are you adding elements to the vector after you save some of the pointers?? That will do it. The vector can resize, which will invalidate all your pointers. pointers to vector elements should generally be avoided. It can be done in some circumstances, if you know what you are doing, really need to, are scrupulously careful, and document clearly so that the software mod next week might not break it. Ptherwise, I'd suggest you just don't do that.

You haven't provided a [MRE] , so a likely guess is all I could come up with. Can't actually tell anything for sure with the lack of detail in your post.

Don't use pointers. It's a good rule, of course there are rare exceptions, but I don't see any for your case.

Don't use raw arrays. Don't use raw pointers. You don't need that e constrictor, but if you insist on having one, spell it this way: e(int to, int p, int v) : to(to), p(p), v(v) {} (member initialisation goes to member initialisation list, and lose the horrible underscore decorations),

@AviBerger Thanks for the advice, I've added extra codes now. Now I've understood the problem is with the automatic expanding vector. When I'm trying to calculate why the two pointers point to the same location, I'm curious that how the vector array exits in the memory. It seems a little bit confusing to me.

The core problem here is that the vector invalidates its iterators (and thus pointers to elements) after modifying operations such as push_back. This is caused by the implementation of the container: when it is not enough capacity for new elements, it creates a new storage and moves everything there and then adds a new element to the end.
You can try to fix this by reserving some initial capacity to prevent this behavior if you know the maximum amount of elements.
for(int i=0; i<m;i++){
 scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&v_temp);
 edge[a].reserve(some_max_number_of_elements)
 

But of course, when you reach this maximum amount, this fix would not work.
That is why storing pointers to vector elements usually not a good idea.

Thx! That really explains my problem
